# How to use electron-print in axios then function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, axios

I want to use [electron-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-print) in axios then function. How to access printer object in then function ?

```
import printer from 'electron-print';

axios
    .get(`${URL}`)
    .then(response => {
        printer.print('test');
    })
TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor
```

or

```
import {printer} from 'electron-print';

axios
    .get(`${URL}`)
    .then(response => {
        // printer is undefined
        printer.print('test');
    })
```

Comment: Do you have install the package electron-printer ? Did you try as the example in the package ?

Comment: Yes I did install and imported.

Comment: I assume you have a printer turn to ON and set one by default ?

Comment: problem is not here.I can't access printer object in then function. Comes undefined.import printer from 'electron-print';

axios
    .get(`${URL}`)
    .then(response => {
        // printer is undefined
        printer.print('test');
    })

Comment: could you try import {print} from 'electron-print'

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: `import printer from 'electron-print';` works, but `BrowserWindow` used by electron-print is not a constructor in your project context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are `import` the lib, as you can see in the electron-print doc, it's a `require`.

As I tell you in comment, can you try to copy/paste this :

```
import {print} from 'electron-print';

axios
    .get(`${URL}`)
    .then(response => print('test'));
```

Cause you did wrong with :

```
import {printer} ...
    ...
    print('test'));
```